# how to implement Java program in cloud computing??I

Tags: javascript, cloud

I created JAVA program which uses external library called `FLANAGAN.JAR`.I want to implement the same program in cloud.For cloud computing `JAVASCRIPT` is necessary.But I am new to `JAVASCRIPT`.I dont know how to implement my java program in cloud.
Shall i post my code.??Give me any suggestions or idea?

Answer (score 0):

No javascript is not a necessity for cloud. You may run your code in many different ways on the cloud. As you did not give any details about your code or application, it is difficult to offer a proper way, but you  may want to check Amazons Elastic Beanstalk for a better understanding to run your code i. Cloud computing is too wide, you may run your code on the cloud in some different ways.

Comment: Did you read my comment? You may run your code with the help of Beanstalk. If you read about it and tried smt I may, otherwise no. You should try first.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can run your code on the cloud depends on the provider you use. Firstly, you will need to choose between an IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service) or a PaaS (Platform as a Service) to put your application on the cloud.

On an IaaS you need to choose the OS you want, like for example Linux Ubuntu, and then you have to install/configure everything as if it is your own computer. If you want to avoid this configuration process, you can use a PaaS.

If your Java program is based on a Tomcat 7 stack, then maybe this [guide](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html) will help you out to understand a way in which you can do it on a specific PaaS.